# Show Local Notifications When App is Killed or in Background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications

I have an HQ Answer bot that is in the form of an iOS app. Basically, I have the entire bot completed and it runs once the HQ Trivia websocket opens, however I am having issues with the last step, which is to send the best answer from the bot to the user in the form of a push notification, since they will be using the HQ app when the game is live and the bot is running. In my viewDidLoad I have the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getSocketURL()

    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)

}
```

getSocketURL() checks to see if the game is live and if so it runs the bot, however I want this to operate when the user has the app killed or it is in the background.

Finally here is where the notification should be sent locally when the bot finds the correct answer:

```
private func getMatches()
{
    let options = [answer1, answer2, answer3]
    AnswerController.answer(for: question, answers: options) { answer in

        print("Predicted correct answer: \(answer.correctAnswer)")
        print("-----")

        self.bestAnswer = answer.correctAnswer

        self.sendNotification(question: self.question, answer: "Best Answer: \(self.bestAnswer)") // Send the user a notification

        self.updateLabels()
    }
}
```

To sum up, I am looking for a way that will let the bot run whenever the game is live without the user having the app open and in the foreground, since they will be in the HQ app. Is there any way to do this with local notifications and if no what steps would I have to take to do something like this using something like Firebase, that is if I still want the bot to run locally on the user's phone.

Comment: If the user has killed the app then it is dead and cannot execute any code. If the user has moved your app to the background then it will be suspended and can only respond to specific events; it cannot monitor a websocket. It sounds like yo needs push notifications from a server rather than local notifications

Comment: Is there anyway to do this via background modes? It would only be for a few minutes while the game's socket is open and would not drain battery. I don't plan on publishing this app anyway, it's mostly for testing purposes and my own sake.

Comment: You can call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` when your app enters the background to get up to 3 minutes of background execution time.